# How to acces WildFly Servers via code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wildfly

I'm developing an eclipse plugin, and I need to find all servers in WildFly and to manage them. How can I acces this list?  For Example to get in a list this one:[image: WildFly Servers]

And if there is a way to run it from code, how to run it?

Comment: What do you mean by "all servers in WildFly"?

Comment: I attached an image with one, I guess there can be more... so how I can get programmatically this server an to display it name in my list?

Comment: You may want to look at how [JBoss Tools](https://github.com/jbosstools) does it. I've got no idea how it's done.